# Do not understand the custom function in Sequelize nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, jestjs, sequelize.js

```
const testUser = await User.create({
            name: "Divya Ranat",
            email: "divyaranat@email.com"
        });
        const testBoard1 = await Board.create({
            type: "Wood",
            description: "Round",
            rating: 7
        });
        const testBoard2 = await Board.create({
            type: "Metal",
            description: "Square",
            rating: 9
        });

        await testUser.addBoards([testBoard1, testBoard2]);
        const foundBoards = await testUser.getBoards();


        const foundUser = await testBoard1.getUser();
        console.log(foundUser)
```

I was expecting the addBoards(), getBoards() and getUser() function to throw an error.
I don't understand what the addBoards(), getBoards() and getUser() does too

Comment: ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#special-methodsmixins-added-to-instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
const testUser = await User.create({
            name: "Divya Ranat",
            email: "divyaranat@email.com"
        });
```

returns an sequelize instance to testUser.
The instance has the data and several methods/functions.

Example: with

```
await testUser.update({property: value})
```

you can update exactly that record in the db, instaead of:

```
await User.update({property: value},{where: { id })
```

Now if you use associations between models, sequelize adds functions to the instance like addBoards.

It will throw an error if you pass wrong data.

Comment: Thanks sir
I already got the solution
But your answer cleared alot of doubt I had about the solution from this link https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#special-methodsmixins-added-to-instances shared by @Emma
Thanks very much